# Queries separated by union

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, Table a, Table b and Table c have same field names but Table d is having different field names, but I need to join the queries and have to be exported as a CSV file.

```
       select a.name,a.age,b.addr from a,b where a.rid=b.tid UNION select 
       a.name,a.age,c.addr from a,c where a.uiroll=c.piroll
```

I need to join table d also , but it has some fields and what I require are d.group and d.project and they are related to table a as d.uon=a.von

The result in cvs file should be as

```
     name     age     addr    group    project
```

and also the values.

Comment: first you say d only has group and project fields, then it suddenly have a "uon" field?

Comment: select a.name,a.age,b.addr from a,b where a.rid=b.tid JOIN select 
       a.name,a.age,c.addr from a,c where a.uiroll=c.piroll  JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like :

```
SELECT a.name, a.age, b.addr, d.group, d.project 
FROM a, b, d 
WHERE a.rid=b.tib 
AND d.uon=a.von 
UNION 
SELECT a.name, a.age, c.addr, d.group, d.project 
FROM a, c, d 
WHERE a.uiroll=c.piroll 
AND d.uon=a.von
```

Comment: supppose if i have one more table e and i require e.time, where a.iif=e.yyf ,i just have to give one more AND a.iif=e.yyf in query right

Comment: sorry it is because the i used some more fields, and the no: of fields used in each query in UNION was different, will have to make some adjustments for making no: of columns equal

Comment: Yes that's the thing with UNION, you need to have the same fields on each side

Comment: @Johanna let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2154/discussion-between-look4php-and-johanna)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, a.age, b.addr, d.group, d.project 
from a
 LEFT JOIN b 
on a.rid = b.tid
 LEFT JOIN c
on a.uiroll = c.piroll
 LEFT JOIN d
on a.von = d.uon;
```

Comment: c.addr? how can that be displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name,a.age,b.addr, d.group. d.project
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.rid=b.tid
INNER JOIN d ON a.von=d.uon
UNION
SELECT a.name,a.age,c.addr, d.group. d.project
FROM a
INNER JOIN d ON a.von=d.uon
INNER JOIN c ON a.uiroll=c.piroll
```

Your description wasn't quite clear, but I guess this is what you want. You should also have a look at the [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) syntax. Joins are essential when working with relational databases.

Comment: but what about c.addr, if i use it in this query it would be displayed  left to b.addr right, the result should be like                    name     age     addr    group    project.  THis have to be displayed in cvs file